# MC Connect: Too much contacts after sync

Tags: marketing-cloud, data, servicecloud, marketing-cloud-connect

here are my synchronized Data Sources
[image]

I understand that Lead and Accounts are counted as Contacts. But the SAP Data is only data which belongs to Accounts, but in the moment it is counted as additional contacts. What can I do that this does not happen? 
In the moment I over a Mio. Contacts in my MC.

Thanks
Oliver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm taking it from your question that you're using Person Accounts? SFMC doesn't send to the Account, it uses the Contact associated with the Account through the PersonContactID as the contact. It's more a reflection of the mess that belies Person Accounts in CRM than Marketing Cloud getting it wrong. CRM's the one that's actually charging you double for the storage, as it papers over what's a fundamentally B2B data model.

Accounts are just data, not "Contacts" in terms of SFMC billing.

Comment: I'm not sure what this means for me when I'm trying to reduce the number of contacts in my SFMC. Is it wrong to use PersonAccounts and shall I switch to contacts instead?

Comment: Your Account records are not a "Population" and DO NOT count towards your quota of Contacts. The Population is based on your Contacts coming from Salesforce CRM. These are your population and sendable records. SFMC notionally gives you a "storage" quota and Account records (along with all your other data) would count towards this (somehow), although I doubt very much that SFMC has developed any effective way of metering your storage usage, let alone charging you for it. Think of it as more of a "fair usage" policy for the time-being. Pausing your Contacts synchronisation doesn't make sense.

Comment: CRM's based on a Business to Business data model where you have Accounts and Contacts. They evolved this as they saw the opportunity to sell the CRM product to Business to Consumer clients and cooked up "Person Accounts". To users, it looks like you have a single "Person" record. Behind the scenes a bunch of Cellotape and Blu Tack that glues together two objects - Account and Contact. Each record counts as storage - 2K for the Account and 2K for the Contact. Marketing Cloud charges you mainly for the Contact.

Comment: Leads are also a Population. As with Contacts, these WILL count towards your SFMC Contact quota. None of your other synchronised objects do the same and are merely "Data".

Answer (score 1):

Just tagging on to this because my company is dealing with a huge battle right now with Person Accounts and the Marketing All Contacts list.

According to Salesforce Documentation ANY Contact, Lead, User, or PersonAccount Data source will be counted against your contact limit: [Documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_cab_contact_definition_and_count_determination.htm&type=5) (see final paragraph)

What this means is that is that you are effectively getting duplication if you are using the Account Synchronized Data Source as Salesforce set it up for you.

1. Disable Contact Sync
2. Add a formula field on the PersonAccount record for the CaseSafeID of the contact record
3. Sync that field over in Marketing Cloud and drive all process off that ID as appose to the PersonAccountID

Which really depends on how important reserving that data that you have already accumulated inside Marketing Cloud means to your process. We opted for a hard delete of the old person account ID data but that really more boils down to your own company needs.

Answer (score 0):

This is problem with Sync data you can not filter, it brings or sync with crm object and bring all to Marketing Cloud and if you attach as population then all becomes your contacts and on top you cannot delete or reduce the size of your contacts. You have to disconnect your salesforce integration and ask MC support to remove contacts from you contact builder.